# Python's Turtle graphics always crashes on second run

Tags: python, python-turtle

Everytime I run Turtle Graphics related code on Python for the second time, it always crashes or the program doesn't respond and just shows a white screen with nothing on it.

When I restart the program, the code works normally and has no errors.

I tried running this:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.forward(100)

turtle.mainloop()
turtle.bye
```

Pretty simple code that has no reason to go wrong, but it fails to run multiple times except for the first try.

All codes I failed to run ran perfectly well on other PCs. So it isn't a miswritten code related proplem.

I never had this problem with other codes that doesn't use Turtle Graphics. Only when I run the code more than once it happens.

This is the error message I got:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: initialized

Thread 0x00004dd0 (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\parentpoller.py", line 89 in run
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 930 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00003aac (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 619 in recv_multipart
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\session.py", line 809 in recv
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 135 in poll_one
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 125 in poll_thread
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910 in run
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 930 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000026c8 (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 312 in wait
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 574 in wait
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 829 in run
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 58 in needs_sqlite
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\decorator.py", line 232 in fun
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 930 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00000f9c (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 315 in _select
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 324 in select
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1854 in _run_once
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596 in run_forever
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199 in start
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\control.py", line 21 in run
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 930 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00004b08 (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\heartbeat.py", line 102 in run
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 930 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00003548 (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 315 in _select
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 324 in select
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1854 in _run_once
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596 in run_forever
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199 in start
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 81 in _thread_main
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910 in run
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 930 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00004430 (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\eventloops.py", line 105 in _loop_qt
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\eventloops.py", line 119 in loop_qt4
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\eventloops.py", line 126 in loop_qt5
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 402 in advance_eventloop
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 741 in _run_callback
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80 in _run
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1890 in _run_once
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596 in run_forever
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199 in start
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677 in start
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 328 in main
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 23 in 
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87 in _run_code
File "C:\Users\lg\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197 in _run_module_as_main
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: `mainloop` blocks and doesn't return (docs say: "Must be the last statement in a turtle graphics program"), so I don't think there's a point to adding more code after it. `bye()` is a method so not calling it has no effect. The code here looks fine, so more details would be necessary to reproduce the problem. How are you running it? What OS? Are you sure this is the exact code?